# Quarto website using global references list

Tags: r, quarto, bibtex

I'm trying to create a Quarto website with bibtex references output to a single (global) bibliography page where the reference citations are spread across qmd files.  The default behavior is to include the bibliography at the bottom of each rendered qmd file (i.e., `index.qmd` and `about.qmd`).

[image]

For Quarto books, a single bibliography file can be created with a blank `references.qmd` file with the following content:

```
### References

::: {#refs}
:::
```

Is there a way to do this with Quarto websites? A MWE structure for a Quarto website:

`_quarto.yml`

```
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "test"
  navbar:
    left:
      - href: index.qmd
        text: Home
      - about.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    toc: true

editor: visual
```

`index.qmd`

````
---
title: "test"
---

This is a Quarto website.

To learn more about Quarto websites visit <https://quarto.org/docs/websites> [@knuth1984].

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

`about.qmd`

````
---
title: "About"
---

About this site [@wickham2019]

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

`references.bib`

```
@article{knuth1984,
  title={Literate programming},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
  journal={The computer journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@book{wickham2019,
  title={Advanced {R}},
  author={Wickham, Hadley},
  year={2019},
  publisher={CRC press}
}
```

Comment: Not need to do anything, just use the `@references` in the text. When you render the site, each article (.qmd file) will have own **References** section.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko not what I'm after, I would like one section with all the references from all the articles.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood your point.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity.